# Force Firefox to run as non-Admin?

Tags: firefox, windows-10, firefox-extensions

Some of my programs running as Administrator launch Firefox via a link they need to open. The problem is, this opens up Firefox as Administrator as well. If I need to open a link from another program that isn't running as Administrator like, my email client, Firefox refuses to respond because I guess Windows thinks my email client isn't permitted to open links on an elevated instance of Firefox. What I end up doing is closing Firefox and re-opening it again as non-Admin.

What I want to happen is ensure that Firefox **never** runs as Administrator **even if** the program that launches it beforehand has elevated permissions. How do I do this on Windows 10 Pro?